# Controller is not redirecting in nested if condition of submit buttons in php using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I submit a search button then load search result but when I click on search result "u_detail" button it redirect to first view not go inside if condition.

```
  public function userSearch()
  {
    $data['main_content'] = 'admin_frontend/home/user_search';
    $this->load->view('admin_frontend/master_layout', $data);

    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
      $search = $this->input->post('data');
      $this->load->model('Admin_models');
      $data['result'] = $this->Admin_models->fetch_data_user_search($search);
      $this->load->view('admin_frontend/home/user_search_result', $data);
      if (isset($_POST['u_detail'])) {
        $data['result'] = $this->Admin_models->show_user_detail($id);
        $this->load->view('admin_frontend/includes/header');
        $this->load->view('admin_frontend/home/user_detail', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin_frontend/includes/footer');
        return;
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Can't understand your question. Please describe clearly.

Comment: i have 3 views in which load in squence
1st search view where i enter search data (1st if  in function above)
2nd search result of search 
i have detail button for every search result
but when i click on detail button it redirect the 1st view not next where i want detail

Comment: I don't know, why you are loading multiple views from same controller. Have you read the documentation?
You need to write separate controller methods to redirect.

Comment: Formatted code. Fixed typos.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code like following.

```
public function user_search()
{
if (isset($_POST['search']))
{
$search=$this->input->post('data');
$this->load->model('Admin_models');
$data['result']=$this->Admin_models->fetch_data_user_search($search);
//$this->load->view('admin_frontend/includes/header'); 
$this->load->view('admin_frontend/home/user_search_result',$data);
//$this->load->view('admin_frontend/includes/footer');
if(isset($_POST['u_detail']))
{
$data['result']=$this->Admin_models->show_user_detail($id);
$this->load->view('admin_frontend/includes/header'); 
$this->load->view('admin_frontend/home/user_detail',$data);
$this->load->view('admin_frontend/includes/footer');
return;
}
}
else
{
$data['main_content'] = 'admin_frontend/home/user_search';
$this->load->view('admin_frontend/master_layout', $data);
}
}
```